# Djnago integration with built html template

Tags: html, css, django

I have built a complete front-end portfolio using HTML, CSS, and js. There is a a email contact form in the webpage and I want to send an email using Django through that contact form. when I tried to integrate it the index page is rendering but the CSS file is not accessible and all the design is disorganized.

In this way my project files are organised:

[image: In this way my project files are organised]

This is the actual design:

[image: This is the actual design]

But after rendering through Django it looks like this:

[image: But after rendering through Django it looks like this]

Answer (score 0):

you just need to address your static files, you can visit [this Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/).

Answer (score 0):

You have your templates folder a bit messy. It actually needs to contain only HTML pages. All the other files move to a 'Static' folder. Then in settings.py you will need to specify this folder as  `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`. This is what would I do at first.